# Issue with position: fixed

Tags: html, css, css-position

When I size my browser window to a width smaller than 770px, the .menu moves down as expected, but when I size it back to a size bigger than 770px, the .menu does not move back up again. This problem seem to only occur in webkit based browsers. This problem did not occur in Firefox and IE.

How can I fix this problem so that when I resize the window to a width bigger than 770px, the .menu will move up again?

Thank you for your time.

link: http://multipop.co

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>MultiPop!</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/1140.css">

        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <meta name="keywords" content="phone, case, holder, car, vent, iphone, 4, 5, 6, galaxy, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, samsung, apple">
        <meta name="description" content="Smartphone car holder and stand ALL IN ONE for iPhone or Android!">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container12">
            <div class="head">
                <a href="#"><img class="logo"src="img/logo.png"></a>
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li data-slide="1">What is It?</li>
                        <li data-slide="2">How?</li>
                        <li data-slide="3">FAQ</li>
                        <li><a class="buy" href="#"><p>Buy Now</p></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="headFix"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column12">
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <div class="column6">
                    hello
                </div>
                <div class="column6">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

1140.css:

```
html,body,div,span,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,address,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,q,small,strong,sub,sup,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td{border:0;margin:0;padding:0}article,aside,figure,figure img,figcaption,hgroup,footer,header,nav,section,video,object{display:block}a img{border:0}figure{position:relative}figure img{width:100%}

/* -------------------- custom .head and .headfix class -------------------- */

.head {
    padding-bottom: 30px !important;
    position: fixed !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9C9C9C;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.headFix {
    height: 106px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.container12, .container16, .head, .headfix{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    width:1140px;
}


.row {margin-bottom:20px;}
.column1, .column2, .column3, .column4, .column5, .column6, .column7, .column8, .column9, .column10, .column11, .column12, .column13, .column14, .column15, .column16 {
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}
.container12 .alpha, .container16 .alpha {margin-left:0;}
.container12 .omega, .container16 .omega {margin-right:0;}
.container12 .column1 {width:75px;}
.container12 .column2 {width:170px;}
.container12 .column3 {width:265px;}
.container12 .column4 {width:360px;}
.container12 .column5 {width:455px;}
.container12 .column6 {width:550px;}
.container12 .column7 {width:645px;}
.container12 .column8 {width:740px;}
.container12 .column9 {width:835px;}
.container12 .column10 {width:930px;}
.container12 .column11 {width:1025px;}
.container12 .column12 {width:1120px;}
.container12 .prefix1 {padding-left:95px;}
.container12 .prefix2 {padding-left:190px;}
.container12 .prefix3 {padding-left:285px;}
.container12 .prefix4 {padding-left:380px;}
.container12 .prefix5 {padding-left:475px;}
.container12 .prefix6 {padding-left:570px;}
.container12 .prefix7 {padding-left:665px;}
.container12 .prefix8 {padding-left:760px;}
.container12 .prefix9 {padding-left:855px;}
.container12 .prefix10 {padding-left:950px;}
.container12 .prefix11 {padding-left:1045px;}

.container16 .column1 {width:51.25px;}
.container16 .column2 {width:122.5px;}
.container16 .column3 {width:193.75px;}
.container16 .column4 {width:265px;}
.container16 .column5 {width:336.25px;}
.container16 .column6 {width:407.5px;}
.container16 .column7 {width:478.75px;}
.container16 .column8 {width:550px;}
.container16 .column9 {width:621.25px;}
.container16 .column10 {width:692.5px;}
.container16 .column11 {width:763.75px;}
.container16 .column12 {width:835px;}
.container16 .column13 {width:906.25px;}
.container16 .column14 {width:977.5px;}
.container16 .column15 {width:1048.75px;}
.container16 .column16 {width:1120px;}
.container16 .prefix1 {padding-left:71.25px;}
.container16 .prefix2 {padding-left:142.5px;}
.container16 .prefix3 {padding-left:213.75px;}
.container16 .prefix4 {padding-left:285px;}
.container16 .prefix5 {padding-left:356.25px;}
.container16 .prefix6 {padding-left:427.5px;}
.container16 .prefix7 {padding-left:498.75px;}
.container16 .prefix8 {padding-left:570px;}
.container16 .prefix9 {padding-left:641.25px;}
.container16 .prefix10 {padding-left:712.5px;}
.container16 .prefix11 {padding-left:783.75px;}
.container16 .prefix12 {padding-left:855px;}
.container16 .prefix13 {padding-left:926.25px;}
.container16 .prefix14 {padding-left:997.5px;}
.container16 .prefix15 {padding-left:1068.75px;}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1160px) {
    .container12, .container16, .head {width:960px;}
    .container12 .column1 {width:60px;}
    .container12 .column2 {width:140px;}
    .container12 .column3 {width:220px;}
    .container12 .column4 {width:300px;}
    .container12 .column5 {width:380px;}
    .container12 .column6 {width:460px;}
    .container12 .column7 {width:540px;}
    .container12 .column8 {width:620px;}
    .container12 .column9 {width:700px;}
    .container12 .column10 {width:780px;}
    .container12 .column11 {width:860px;}
    .container12 .column12 {width:940px;}
    .container12 .prefix1 {padding-left:80px;}
    .container12 .prefix2 {padding-left:160px;}
    .container12 .prefix3 {padding-left:240px;}
    .container12 .prefix4 {padding-left:320px;}
    .container12 .prefix5 {padding-left:400px;}
    .container12 .prefix6 {padding-left:480px;}
    .container12 .prefix7 {padding-left:560px;}
    .container12 .prefix8 {padding-left:640px;}
    .container12 .prefix9 {padding-left:720px;}
    .container12 .prefix10 {padding-left:800px;}
    .container12 .prefix11 {padding-left:880px;}
    .container16 .column1 {width:40px;}
    .container16 .column2 {width:100px;}
    .container16 .column3 {width:160px;}
    .container16 .column4 {width:220px;}
    .container16 .column5 {width:280px;}
    .container16 .column6 {width:340px;}
    .container16 .column7 {width:400px;}
    .container16 .column8 {width:460px;}
    .container16 .column9 {width:520px;}
    .container16 .column10 {width:580px;}
    .container16 .column11 {width:640px;}
    .container16 .column12 {width:700px;}
    .container16 .column13 {width:760px;}
    .container16 .column14 {width:820px;}
    .container16 .column15 {width:880px;}
    .container16 .column16 {width:940px;}
    .container16 .prefix1 {padding-left:60px;}
    .container16 .prefix2 {padding-left:120px;}
    .container16 .prefix3 {padding-left:180px;}
    .container16 .prefix4 {padding-left:240px;}
    .container16 .prefix5 {padding-left:300px;}
    .container16 .prefix6 {padding-left:360px;}
    .container16 .prefix7 {padding-left:420px;}
    .container16 .prefix8 {padding-left:480px;}
    .container16 .prefix9 {padding-left:540px;}
    .container16 .prefix10 {padding-left:600px;}
    .container16 .prefix11 {padding-left:660px;}
    .container16 .prefix12 {padding-left:720px;}
    .container16 .prefix13 {padding-left:780px;}
    .container16 .prefix14 {padding-left:840px;}
    .container16 .prefix15 {padding-left:900px;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    .container12, .container16, .head {width:768px;}
    .container12 .column1 {width:44px;}
    .container12 .column2 {width:108px;}
    .container12 .column3 {width:172px;}
    .container12 .column4 {width:236px;}
    .container12 .column5 {width:300px;}
    .container12 .column6 {width:364px;}
    .container12 .column7 {width:428px;}
    .container12 .column8 {width:492px;}
    .container12 .column9 {width:556px;}
    .container12 .column10 {width:620px;}
    .container12 .column11 {width:684px;}
    .container12 .column12 {width:748px;}
    .container12 .prefix1 {padding-left:64px;}
    .container12 .prefix2 {padding-left:128px;}
    .container12 .prefix3 {padding-left:192px;}
    .container12 .prefix4 {padding-left:256px;}
    .container12 .prefix5 {padding-left:320px;}
    .container12 .prefix6 {padding-left:384px;}
    .container12 .prefix7 {padding-left:448px;}
    .container12 .prefix8 {padding-left:512px;}
    .container12 .prefix9 {padding-left:576px;}
    .container12 .prefix10 {padding-left:640px;}
    .container12 .prefix11 {padding-left:704px;}
    .container16 .column1 {width:28px;}
    .container16 .column2 {width:76px;}
    .container16 .column3 {width:124px;}
    .container16 .column4 {width:172px;}
    .container16 .column5 {width:220px;}
    .container16 .column6 {width:268px;}
    .container16 .column7 {width:316px;}
    .container16 .column8 {width:364px;}
    .container16 .column9 {width:412px;}
    .container16 .column10 {width:460px;}
    .container16 .column11 {width:508px;}
    .container16 .column12 {width:556px;}
    .container16 .column13 {width:604px;}
    .container16 .column14 {width:652px;}
    .container16 .column15 {width:700px;}
    .container16 .column16 {width:748px;}
    .container16 .prefix1 {padding-left:48px;}
    .container16 .prefix2 {padding-left:96px;}
    .container16 .prefix3 {padding-left:144px;}
    .container16 .prefix4 {padding-left:192px;}
    .container16 .prefix5 {padding-left:240px;}
    .container16 .prefix6 {padding-left:288px;}
    .container16 .prefix7 {padding-left:336px;}
    .container16 .prefix8 {padding-left:384px;}
    .container16 .prefix9 {padding-left:432px;}
    .container16 .prefix10 {padding-left:480px;}
    .container16 .prefix11 {padding-left:528px;}
    .container16 .prefix12 {padding-left:576px;}
    .container16 .prefix13 {padding-left:624px;}
    .container16 .prefix14 {padding-left:672px;}
    .container16 .prefix15 {padding-left:720px;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .container12, .container16, .head {width:300px;}
    .container12 .column1, .container16 .column1,
    .container12 .column2, .container16 .column2,
    .container12 .column3, .container16 .column3,
    .container12 .column4, .container16 .column4,
    .container12 .column5, .container16 .column5,
    .container12 .column6, .container16 .column6,
    .container12 .column7, .container16 .column7,
    .container12 .column8, .container16 .column8,
    .container12 .column9, .container16 .column9,
    .container12 .column10, .container16 .column10,
    .container12 .column11, .container16 .column11,
    .container12 .column12, .container16 .column12,
    .container16 .column13,
    .container16 .column14,
    .container16 .column15,
    .container16 .column16, .head {
        margin:0 0 20px 0;
        width:300px;
    }
    .container12 .prefix1, .container12 .prefix2, .container12 .prefix3, .container12 .prefix4, .container12 .prefix5, .container12 .prefix6, .container12 .prefix7, .container12 .prefix8, .container12 .prefix9, .container12 .prefix10, .container12 .prefix11, .container16 .prefix1, .container16 .prefix2, .container16 .prefix3, .container16 .prefix4, .container16 .prefix5, .container16 .prefix6, .container16 .prefix7, .container16 .prefix8, .container16 .prefix9, .container16 .prefix10, .container16 .prefix11, .container16 .prefix12, .container16 .prefix13, .container16 .prefix14, .container16 .prefix15 {padding-left:0;}
    .row, .head {margin:0;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .container12, .container16, .head {width:420px;}
    .container12 .column1, .container16 .column1,
    .container12 .column2, .container16 .column2,
    .container12 .column3, .container16 .column3,
    .container12 .column4, .container16 .column4,
    .container12 .column5, .container16 .column5,
    .container12 .column6, .container16 .column6,
    .container12 .column7, .container16 .column7,
    .container12 .column8, .container16 .column8,
    .container12 .column9, .container16 .column9,
    .container12 .column10, .container16 .column10,
    .container12 .column11, .container16 .column11,
    .container12 .column12, .container16 .column12,
    .container16 .column13,
    .container16 .column14,
    .container16 .column15,
    .container16 .column16, .head {
        margin:0 0 20px 0;
        width:420px;
    }
    .container12 .prefix1, .container12 .prefix2, .container12 .prefix3, .container12 .prefix4, .container12 .prefix5, .container12 .prefix6, .container12 .prefix7, .container12 .prefix8, .container12 .prefix9, .container12 .prefix10, .container12 .prefix11, .container16 .prefix1, .container16 .prefix2, .container16 .prefix3, .container16 .prefix4, .container16 .prefix5, .container16 .prefix6, .container16 .prefix7, .container16 .prefix8, .container16 .prefix9, .container16 .prefix10, .container16 .prefix11, .container16 .prefix12, .container16 .prefix13, .container16 .prefix14, .container16 .prefix15 {padding-left:0;}
    .row, .head {margin:0;}
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after,
.row:before, .row:after,
.container12:before, .container12:after, .container16:before, .container16:after {
    content:'.';
    display:block;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:0;
}
/* http://sonspring.com/journal/clearing-floats */
.clear {
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:0;
}
.row:after, .clearfix:after, .container12:after, .container16:after {clear:both;}
/* For IE7. Move this to separate file when you notice some problems */
.row, .clearfix {zoom: 1;}
img, object, embed {max-width:100%;}
img {height:auto;}
```

style.css:

```
/* -------------------- basic styles -------------------- */


body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
}


/* -------------------- heading -------------------- */

/* .head class in 1140.css */


.logo {
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    clear: both;
}

.menu {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 32px;
    clear: both;
}

.menu li {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: #616161;
}

.buy {
    background-color: #e5482e;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    padding-top: -20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
.buy:hover {
    background-color: #F25B41;
}
.buy:active {
    background-color: #F0725D;
}

.buy p {
    padding-top: 9px;
}

/* -------------------- footer -------------------- */

.footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #9C9C9C;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

/* -------------------- media queries -------------------- */


@media (max-width: 770px) {
    .menu {
        float: none;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post a link, put your code in the question.

Comment: i try in chrome, i work fine

Comment: The problem exists, I tried it on my other computer as well. airi misunderstood what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this seems to be an issue with Chrome.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=147449

You can see a similar (but not exact) issue here: http://jsbin.com/EwuxiJI/9 (this is linked on the Chromium issues page at the bottom)